# Filling Customized tableviewcell Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an iOS application, there are data as strings i retrieved from a server using RestKit. data retrieved successfully and i can print it using NSlog. so i want to view these data in the below tableviewcell.

[image]

so how to implement the tableviewcell to be filled by the list of devices, description and date that i retrieved from the server using RestKit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First question, how are you implementing that TableView?  Using a Nib file?  Storyboard?  Through code only?  Answering that question first, will help in telling you what you need to do next.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, but takes a bit of time. You need to get your backend data into arrays (or something similar) - inside a class that extends UITableViewController, then hook up your UILabels as outlets, and in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, you can pull assign the data to a cell at a particular index.

`cell.deviceDescription.text = [myDataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row];`

Answer (score 0):

you set your cell height

```
tableView.rowHeight=height_you_want;
        or
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return your_row_height;
}
```

Inside **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** You can created three UILabel, modify (background text font color size etc) and add them as subview to the cell or cell.contentView

```
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)];    
lbl.text=@"Your text";
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];    
[cell addSubview:lbl];

//use this accessory type     
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Comment: I already created the cell using interface builder XIB, but i want to read from the NSMutableArray and fill the cell.

Comment: you mean you hav created a cell using interface builder xib. is your question how you can fill the labels from nsmutablearray programmatically?

Comment: have your created .h and .m file for that cell?

Comment: did you try this? youCustomCell.Description.text=@"description_string"; youCustomCell.Date.text=@"Date_string";

Answer (score 0):

create your custom cell with xib.

```
@interface YourCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* deviceNameLbl;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* desciptionLbl;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* dateLbl;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize deviceNameLbl ,.......
......
```

[image]
then in your view controller where you want to display this cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"YourCustomCell";
    YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType];
     if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = (YourCustomCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
      }

   //yourDataArray is a array contains NSDictionary
   cell.deviceNameLbl = [[yourDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey@"deviceName"];
   cell.desciptionLbl = [[yourDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey@"description"];
   cell.dateLbl = [[yourDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey@"date"];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: No need to create the cell with a separate nib file if you are already using Interface Builder for building the tableview.  Just create the UITableViewCell subclass and set the parent class of your UITableView Cell to that class.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create custom `UITableViewCell`
2. Loop through data array in your `UITableViewController`
3. In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you must alloc/init your class

But as @FaddishWorm say's it will take some time